# Is a SDXC card a viable secondary hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, sd-card

I have an SDXC compatible SD slot on my laptop that isn't doing anything and I saw a 128gb SDXC for around $150.

I was wondering if this could be use as a secondary hard drive?

If so, what would be performance pros and cons?

How would it compare to a SSD?

Answer (score 2):

It *could* be used as a second hard drive, but the SD interface will never have anywhere near the same bandwidth as SATA.

Comment: is there a SATA HD that will fit into the open unused SD slot on my laptop?

Answer (score 1):

The SD slot is often a USB device and as such is limited by the speed of that interface as well as the that of the controller . I can see it being used the same way as a *very* large floppy,  but it'll never have the same face melting speed as a proper SSD - the speed is not just the memory type, it is the controller and interface between the computer and storage. I also suspect that SD cards may have less sophisticated wear levelling algorithms than SSD drives andd probably less redundancy (SSDs have spare memory locations to handle wear i believe).

Comment: Actually no, on laptops it's usually a PCI device.